# Property not found on object of type 'UITableViewCell *'

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am getting this error while working on my xcode project

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DateTimeCell1";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

  if (cell == nil)
  {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                 reuseIdentifier:@"cell" ];
  }


  NSString *sysDeliveryType=[[jsonData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"sysord_DeliveryType"];
  NSString *sysExpDeliveryTime=[[jsonData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"sysord_ExpectedDeliveryTime"];
  NSString *sysOrderDateTime=[[jsonData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"sysord_OrderDateTime"];
  NSLog(@"%@",sysDeliveryType);
  cell.lblDeliveryPickUP.text=sysDeliveryType;
  cell.lblexpDeliveryTime.text=sysExpDeliveryTime;
  cell.lblsysOrderPlacedTime.text=sysOrderDateTime;
  return cell;
}
```

Also outlate are given properly but this  Error  Of property not found display in my Code

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the `cell` to `DateTimeCell`.

For example: `[[(DateTimeCell *)cell lblDeliveryPickUP] setText:sysDeliveryType];`

The labels you try to set there are not properties of `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Or you can use `performSelector` or KVC `setValue:forKey:`

Comment: Your code can be `((DateTimeCell *)cell).lblDeliveryPickUP.text = sysDeliveryType`. Actually, I like this one more

Comment: He should really be declaring `cell` as a `DateTimeCell` instead of a `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Of course the most important issue is that the line that actually creates a new cell should replace `UITableViewCell` with `DateTimeCell` (or whatever the actual class name is).

Comment: [[(DateTimeCell *)cell lblDeliveryPickUP] setText:sysDeliveryType];   Ask me  Expected expression

Answer (score -1):

Declare the cell to be the desired type, and supply the correct identifier to the dequeue method.

> DateTimeCell1 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Comment: Would this help for finding the property of the cell? Or just for improvement?

Comment: Property not found - compile time error, so there is no way dequeue method have something to do with it. 
Your advice would be helpful only in case of runtime `unrecognised selector` exception

Comment: The OP's code declares the CellIdentifier for DateTimeCell1, but doesn't use it.  I think this is why he is not getting the properties.  There is no mention of compile time vs runtime error.  If he wants a DateTimeCell1, he should create one, and then see if it works.

Comment: @Rayfleck It has nothing to do with the identifier. That can be anything. It's simply a matter of the variable being the wrong type (`UITableViewCell` instead of the needed `DateTimeCell`).

Comment: Even if he declares `DateTimeCell1* cell`, if he passes the wrong identifier, he won't get the right type. So he needs to do both. I edited my answer.